# Simple question about pre/post hard fork of July 2016

Tags: ethereum-classic, hardforks

I have searched the messages and, while I did find some info on the hard fork, I didn't see my answer.  I believe it is because it is such a simple question.  Thank you for any clarification you can provide!
I am a novice regarding cryptocurrency in general.  If you owned 50 Ethereum prior to the hard fork in July 2016, would those 50 coins be considered ETH or Classic?  I have read some conflicting articles trying to figure this out myself.  Some say that Classic forked off ETH to remain "pure"; thus, I would think the 50 would be considered ETH.  I read a different article saying that the Classic remained "pure" and ETH forked off it, meaning the original 50 would be Classic.  Now, reading some message threads on here, it seems to be that the fork gave owners the same of each ETH and Classic; therefore, you would have 50 of each.  I sincerely hope someone can answer this for me.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

> it seems to be that the fork gave owners the same of each ETH and Classic; therefore, you would have 50 of each

Correct. A snapshot was taken of the world state, and all accounts and their balances were duplicated to the new ETC chain. You would have had both 50 ETH and 50 ETC.